# Show commit messages after merge

Tags: git

I would like to receive a beautiful readable list of new commits with their messages after merging, instead of the default list of changed files. Something that would look like:

```
[21.05.13 10:03] User Superuser <his@mail.com>: f56dc3db33f7bae45edb48e4f051859d469a8f37
                 Fixed something
[23.05.13 10:03] User Duperuser <his@mail.net>: cb3fd7312ec6d712f8fcff27b508f74799f645b4
                 Merge remote branch 'origin/master' into duperbranch
```

I will be using `post-merge` hook, but do I find latest commit messages that weren't merged?

Comment: How did you create the hook?  According to `git help hooks` post-merge is still valid (git 1.8.3.2).

Comment: @AndrewMyers I did create it in `.git/hooks` and filled with `echo 123` then merged, nothing happened. May I be missing something here?

Comment: Did you set it to executable? Also, per the man page `is not executed if the merge failed due to conflicts.`.

Comment: I may have forgotten to do this, will test as soon as I can and reply back, thank you. But what about printing commit messages that are new? Like I could probably run `git log` with some prettifiers, but that doesn't filter it for only new commits

Comment: @AndrewMyers it works with the executable flag, thank you! But the main question is to get the latest commits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the merged in commits I would do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

parents=( $( git show --pretty=%P $1 ) )
# First is branch we merged into, rest are parents which were merged.
echo First: $parents[1]
echo Rest: $parents[2,-1]

# For each parent we merged in get commits that are new to original HEAD.
for p in $parents[2,-1]
do
    git log $parents[1]..$p
done
```

Run this with `./script.sh $commit`, in your case you can just replace `$1` with `HEAD` for the hook.

You can experiment with pretty printing log options to get what you like.

Comment: Thank you, will try asap and reply back!